# Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.Customization; Constructor error: Can't find

Tags: java, jmeter, jsonassert

I use jmeter to comapre  json data.use org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.
suceess in idea with jdk8, but failed in jmeter
this is error info.

> **i have imported jsonassert-1.5.1.jar and android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar into %Jmeter%lib，jackson use 2.13.3 version.jmeter version is 5.5 .**

```
Response code:500
Response message:org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.Customization; import org.skyscreamer.jsonasse . . . '' : Constructor error: Can't find constructor: org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.comparator.CustomComparator( org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompareMode, org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.Customization ) in class: org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.comparator.CustomComparator
```

this is beanshell sampler ,the code i write in the jmeter

```
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.Customization;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompare;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompareMode;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompareResult;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.ValueMatcher;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.comparator.CustomComparator;
import org.json.JSONException;


String newResponseMessage = vars.get("new_S{custNo}");
String oldResponseMessage = vars.get("old_S{custNo}");
log.info("oldRes"+oldResponseMessage);
log.info("newRes"+newResponseMessage);
ValueMatcher matcher = new ValueMatcher() {
            public boolean equal(Object o1, Object o2) {
                return true;
            }
        };
Customization customization = new Customization("orgSeqNo", matcher);
JSONCompareResult result;
try {
    result = JSONCompare.compareJSON(newResponseMessage, oldResponseMessage, new CustomComparator(JSONCompareMode.NON_EXTENSIBLE,customization));
    if (result.passed()) {
        System.out.println("no different");
    } else {
        System.out.println(result.getMessage());
        log.error(result.getMessage());
    //    ctx.getEngine().stopTest();
    }
}catch (JSONException e){
    log.error("Beanshell failure: ", e);
    throw ex;
}
```

[code in jmeter beanshell sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx4wM.png)

[error info picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObqQh.png)

**i have imported jsonassert-1.5.1.jar and android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar into %Jmeter%lib  and %Jmeter%/lib/ext both，jackson use 2.13.3 version.jmeter version is 5.5 .**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2pHW.png)

I use jmeter to comapre  json data.use org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.
suceess in idea with jdk8, but failed in jmeter
these are codes i write with jdk8,success run,but failed in jmeter

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

```
public class Main {
    static String jsonStr1 = "{\"orgSeqNo\":\"123123\",\"code\":200,\"person\":{\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"partyName\":\"john\",\"partyCertType\":\"10100\",\"partyCertNo\":\"320925199612122314\",\"partyStatus\":\"1\",\"addresses\":[{\"addrId\":\"1\",\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"city\":\"suchou\",\"detailAddr\":\"asdfghqwe\",\"addrType\":103,\"phone\":\"13213137625\"},{\"addrId\":\"2\",\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"city\":\"suchou\",\"detailAddr\":\"asdfghqwe\",\"addrType\":\"101\",\"phone\":\"13213137625\"},{\"addrId\":\"3\",\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"city\":\"suchou\",\"detailAddr\":\"asdfghqwe\",\"addrType\":\"102\",\"phone\":\"13213137625\"}]},\"message\":\"ok\"}";

    static String jsonStr2 = "{\"orgSeqNo\":\"12e9fc45c09b4a69b7aa2bbcb1313cba\",\"code\":200,\"person\":{\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"partyName\":\"john\",\"partyCertType\":\"10100\",\"partyCertNo\":\"320925199612122314\",\"partyStatus\":\"1\",\"addresses\":[{\"addrId\":\"1\",\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"city\":\"suchou\",\"detailAddr\":\"asdfghqwe\",\"addrType\":\"103\",\"phone\":\"13213137625\"},{\"addrId\":\"2\",\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"city\":\"suchou\",\"detailAddr\":\"asdfghqwe\",\"addrType\":\"101\",\"phone\":\"13213137625\"},{\"addrId\":\"3\",\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"city\":\"suchou\",\"detailAddr\":\"asdfghqwe\",\"addrType\":\"102\",\"phone\":\"13213137625\"}]},\"message\":\"ok\"}";
    
    static String jsonStr3 = "{\"orgSeqNo\":\"12e9fc45c09b4a69b7aa2bbcb1313cba\",\"code\":200,\"person\":{\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"partyName\":\"john\",\"partyCertType\":\"10100\",\"partyCertNo\":\"320925199612122314\",\"partyStatus\":\"1\",\"addresses\":[{\"addrId\":\"2\",\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"city\":\"suchou\",\"detailAddr\":\"asdfghqwe\",\"addrType\":\"101\",\"phone\":\"13213137625\"},{\"addrId\":\"1\",\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"city\":\"suchou\",\"detailAddr\":\"asdfghqwe\",\"addrType\":\"103\",\"phone\":\"13213137625\"},{\"addrId\":\"3\",\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"city\":\"suchou\",\"detailAddr\":\"asdfghqwe\",\"addrType\":\"102\",\"phone\":\"13213137625\"}]},\"message\":\"ok\"}";
    
    static String jsonStr4 = "{\"orgSeqNo\":\"12e9fc45c09b4a69b7aa2bbcb1313cba\",\"code\":200,\"person\":{\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"partyName\":\"john\",\"partyCertType\":\"10100\",\"partyCertNo\":\"320925199612122314\",\"partyStatus\":\"1\",\"addresses\":[{\"addrId\":\"1\",\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"city\":\"suchou\",\"detailAddr\":\"asdfghqwe\",\"addrType\":103,\"phone\":\"13213137625\"},{\"addrId\":\"2\",\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"city\":\"suchou\",\"detailAddr\":\"asdfghqwe\",\"addrType\":\"101\",\"phone\":\"13213137625\"},{\"addrId\":\"3\",\"partyId\":\"10000000001\",\"city\":\"suchou\",\"detailAddr\":\"asdfghqwe\",\"addrType\":\"102\",\"phone\":\"13213137625\"}]},\"message\":\"ok\"}";



    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        Customization customization = new Customization("orgSeqNo", (o1, o2) -> true);
        ValueMatcher matcher = new ValueMatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean equal(Object o1, Object o2) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        Customization customization = new Customization("orgSeqNo", matcher);
        JSONCompareResult result = null;
        try {
            result  = JSONCompare.compareJSON(jsonStr1, jsonStr3, new CustomComparator(JSONCompareMode.NON_EXTENSIBLE,customization));
            if (result1.passed()) {
                System.out.println("no different");
            } else {
                System.out.println(result.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

next is result,i want jmeter also like this result

```
person.addresses[addrId=1].addrType
Expected: 103
     got: 103
```

[Program execution result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYcKg.png)

**i have imported jsonassert-1.5.1.jar and android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar into %Jmeter%lib，jackson use 2.13.3 version.jmeter version is 5.5 .**

run success in jvm , but error info in jmeter...

Answer (score 0):

[Beanshell](https://beanshell.github.io/) != Java so even given your code "suceess in idea with jdk8" it doesn't necessarily mean that it will "suceess" in JMeter's Beanshell components.

[Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so my expectation is that if you switch to the JSR223 Sampler and use `groovy` your code will "suceess" as well.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thank you very much! I switch to the JSR223 Sampler and use groovy .success .